# How do I enable the mod_rewrite Apache module for Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, apache2, php, mysql

In other linux like CentOS, it works but i am not getting it running in Ubuntu 11.04.

```
/var/www/html/folder/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Did you ensure the RewriteEngine is on?

You'll want to verify that the mod is enabled - just look for rewrite.load symlink in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled. If not, run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable it. Restart apache using `sudo service apache2 restart` and provided your .htaccess syntax is correct this will work.

Otherwise you will need to paste more information about your .htaccess file.

Comment: Does `sudo a2enmod rewrite` have to be executed from a particular directory? I.e. do I need to `cd` to anywhere first?

Comment: `sudo: a2enmod: command not found`